# Using a selected value in <option> Angular.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I am just beginning to learn using Angular.js but I couldn't figure out this one:

I want to show items from the array where the selected `value ="song.title"` matches the `song.title` from the array.

This is my code

```
<select>
     <option ng-repeat="song in songs.tracks">{{song.title}}</option>
</select>
```

Now I wanna show more of the selected songs array in this  :

```
<section ng-repeat="song in songs.tracks">
     <div class="panel" ng-show="panel.isSelected(1)" >

<!-- in here i wanna show stuff from the array of the selected song -->

     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/6e8ZC8oLgui72jeyrump?p=preview)

```
 <div>
  Select Song :: <select ng-model="selectedSong" ng-options="song as song.title for song in songs.tracks">
  </select>

  </div>
  <div>
  Selected Song :: 

  {{selectedSong}}
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! I haven't come across the ng-options expression yet , can you explain me how it works ?

Comment: Do you know what condition I need to give my ng-click to a button so i can display the first item from the 'song' array when clicking it ?

Answer (score 0):

So, first of all You have to attach model to your select tag, to do it use `ng-model` directive. In `option` tag set attribute `value="{{song.id}}"` so your model will contain selected song id.

Second thing, your loop displaying div with stuff from array is wrong, because in each loop you pass 1 to your `isSelected` method. Better is `isSelected($index)`. But you don`t have to do this loop, just use your model containing selected id in songs array

```
<div>{{songs[yourmodel].title}}</div>
```